# table creation in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to merge a sql script which create a table and a pl/sql script which insert data in that table. Customer wishes

My idea was to do the table creation in pl sql. But it doesn't work. Create is not allowed in the begin part. A solution I've seen is to do this in an execute immediate statement. In practice I 've tried this :

```
    SET serveroutput ON
    spool 03_CREATE_CATEGORIEDECL.log

    BEGIN
     execute immediate 'create table CATEGORIEDECLARATION ( 
     nIdCategorieDeclaration  NUMBER(10)   not null,
     ...
     constraint PK_CATDECLA primary key (nIdCategorieDeclaration)
    )';

select c.nidcalendrier into millesime from calendrier c where c.smillesime = '2010';

-- Lignes relatives au formulaire CA3
INSERT into CATEGORIEDECLARATION (nIdCategorieDeclaration,nIdTypeFormulaire,sLibelle,sType,sAide,sTexte,sTexte2,sTypeAffichage,bAffichage,sInterval,nIdCalendrier) 
values (seq_CATEGORIEDECLARATION.nextval,'5','Autres cas  (zone de saisie libre)', 'SOMME_A_DEDUIRE','','',NULL,'CAT_AUTRE_CAS', 1, 'POSITIF',millesime);

COMMIT;
    END; 
    /
    spool off
```

I get an error on the end keyword, it wasn't expected. So my question is how to create a table in a pl/sql script? Do I have to keep those 2 actions in 2 differents scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 syntax errors, both concerning semi-colons.  Try this:

```
BEGIN
 execute immediate 'create table CATEGORIEDECLARATION (
 nIdCategorieDeclaration  NUMBER(10)   not null,
 ...
 constraint PK_CATDECLA primary key (nIdCategorieDeclaration)
)';
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks now the creation works fine. Now it does not allow me to concat the creation and the insert in the same begin block. The error is : the table does not exist. I tried commit in between, it doesn't work better. Do you have an idea?

Comment: You would need 2 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE starements: BEGIN
 execute immediate 'create table CATEGORIEDECLARATION (
 nIdCategorieDeclaration  NUMBER(10)   not null,
 constraint PK_CATDECLA primary key (nIdCategorieDeclaration)
)';
 execute immediate 'insert into CATEGORIEDECLARATION (nIdCategorieDeclaration) VALUES (123)';
END;

Answer (score 3):

Before checking out the snippets please keep in mind that at the moment of this writing I didn't have access to a Oracle database to test them in any way. Everything that follows is written from memory.

I assume you are using sqlplus to run your scripts. Can't you simply put the create statement and a PL/SQL block in the file?

```
SET serveroutput ON

spool 03_CREATE_CATEGORIEDECL.log

create table CATEGORIEDECLARATION ( 
     nIdCategorieDeclaration  NUMBER(10)   not null,
     ...
constraint PK_CATDECLA primary key (nIdCategorieDeclaration)
/


BEGIN
  select c.nidcalendrier into millesime from calendrier c where c.smillesime = '2010';
  -- Lignes relatives au formulaire CA3
  INSERT into CATEGORIEDECLARATION (nIdCategorieDeclaration,nIdTypeFormulaire,sLibelle,sType,sAide,sTexte,sTexte2,sTypeAffichage,bAffichage,sInterval,nIdCalendrier) 
  values (seq_CATEGORIEDECLARATION.nextval,'5','Autres cas  (zone de saisie libre)', 'SOMME_A_DEDUIRE','','',NULL,'CAT_AUTRE_CAS', 1, 'POSITIF',millesime);

  COMMIT;
END; 
/
spool off
```

Another approach is to generate the script dynamically and call it

`SET serveroutput ON
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET LINESIZE 800
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET ECHO OFF`

SPOOL gen_cr_table_script.sql
SELECT 'create table CATEGORIEDECLARATION ( 
     nIdCategorieDeclaration  NUMBER(10)   not null,
     ...
     constraint PK_CATDECLA primary key (nIdCategorieDeclaration)
    )'
  FROM SYS.DUAL
/
SPOOL OFF

@gen_cr_table_script.sql

-- you can generate the insert script here if needed
-- spool gen_ins_script.sql
-- select ...
-- spool off
-- spool 03_CREATE_CATEGORIEDECL.log
-- @gen_ins_script.sql
-- spool off
-- add commit where appropriate

Or you can use a plain sqlplus approach without pl/sql blocks

`create table CATEGORIEDECLARATION ( 
     nIdCategorieDeclaration  NUMBER(10)   not null,
     ...
constraint PK_CATDECLA primary key (nIdCategorieDeclaration)
/`

INSERT INTO  CATEGORIEDECLARATION (nIdCategorieDeclaration,nIdTypeFormulaire,sLibelle,sType,sAide,sTexte,sTexte2,sTypeAffichage,bAffichage,sInterval,nIdCalendrier)
     SELECT (seq_CATEGORIEDECLARATION.nextval,'5','Autres cas  (zone de saisie libre)', 'SOMME_A_DEDUIRE','','',NULL,'CAT_AUTRE_CAS', 1, 'POSITIF',c.nidcalendrier);
       FROM calendrier c
      WHERE c.smillesime = '2010'
/
COMMIT
/

Comment: Indeed I use the first approach you provide. At first I thought the customer wanted a full pl/sql approach. At least I learned some pl/sql tips